# Cisco switchport is solid amber

Tags: cisco, ios, cisco-catalyst

I have a port on my switch that is showing a solid amber light.   I have tried to shutdown this port, but it still shows the solid amber.  This switch is production critical so, I cannot reboot it until there is an appropriate scheduled window to do so.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Here are my settings on the port:

```
#sh run int gi1/0/31

  interface GigabitEthernet1/0/31
  switchport access vlan 144
  switchport mode access
  spanning-tree portfast

#sh int gi1/0/31 status

  Port      Name               Status       Vlan       Duplex  Speed Type
  Gi1/0/31  ProcessTestVlan144 notconnect   144          auto   auto 10/100/1000

#sh int gi1/0/31


 GigabitEthernet1/0/31 is down, line protocol is down (notconnect)
      Hardware is Gigabit Ethernet, address is 34db.fd4e.601f (bia 34db.fd4e.601f)
      Description: ProcessTestVlan144
      MTU 1500 bytes, BW 10000 Kbit, DLY 1000 usec,
         reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
      Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
      Keepalive set (10 sec)
      Auto-duplex, Auto-speed, media type is 10/100/1000BaseTX
      input flow-control is off, output flow-control is unsupported
      ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
      Last input 17:54:14, output 17:54:14, output hang never
      Last clearing of "show interface" counters 8w3d
      Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 0
      Queueing strategy: fifo
      Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
      5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
      5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
         320 packets input, 26672 bytes, 0 no buffer
         Received 320 broadcasts (320 multicasts)
         0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
         0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
         0 watchdog, 320 multicast, 0 pause input
         0 input packets with dribble condition detected
         4356 packets output, 312974 bytes, 0 underruns
         0 output errors, 0 collisions, 2 interface resets
         0 babbles, 0 late collision, 0 deferred
         0 lost carrier, 0 no carrier, 0 PAUSE output
         0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out

#sh int gi1/0/31 switchport


 Name: Gi1/0/31
     Switchport: Enabled
     Administrative Mode: static access
     Operational Mode: down
     Administrative Trunking Encapsulation: dot1q
     Negotiation of Trunking: Off
     Access Mode VLAN: 144 (VLAN0144)
     Trunking Native Mode VLAN: 1 (default)
     Administrative Native VLAN tagging: enabled
     Voice VLAN: none
     Administrative private-vlan host-association: none
     Administrative private-vlan mapping: none
     Administrative private-vlan trunk native VLAN: none
     Administrative private-vlan trunk Native VLAN tagging: enabled
     Administrative private-vlan trunk encapsulation: dot1q
     Administrative private-vlan trunk normal VLANs: none
     Administrative private-vlan trunk associations: none
     Administrative private-vlan trunk mappings: none
     Operational private-vlan: none
     Trunking VLANs Enabled: ALL
     Pruning VLANs Enabled: 2-1001
     Capture Mode Disabled
     Capture VLANs Allowed: ALL

     Protected: false
      Unknown unicast blocked: disabled
      Unknown multicast blocked: disabled
      Appliance trust: none
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Check for err-disables

  show int status err-disable
- Shutdown down the port, wait 10 seconds, bring the port back up

  shutdown
  /* wait 10 seconds */
  no shutdown
- reseat cable
- Use your laptop to plug directoly into that port to see if
  anything changes. If it goes up and functions then its something down
  the line that's broken/misconfigured.

Comment: - Err-Disable didn't show anything.   - I had tried shutdown previously, and it did not help.  - I had unplugged the cable several times and knew it was good.  - Plugged in my laptop and the port took right off !!  I think there was a switch downstream that was setup for a trunk port not an access port.